# CFloop within a loop

Tags: coldfusion

I want to loop through a query and for every row iteration to display two ids per row. I have tried a loop within a loop, but it just outputs all of the rows twice.

```
<!--- sample query --->
<cfset sheets = queryNew("")>
<cfset queryAddColumn(sheets, "id", [1,2,3,4])>

<table>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="sheets">
<tr>
    <cfloop query="sheets">
        <td align="center">#sheets.id#</td>
    </cfloop>
</tr>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested loops are not the way to do this.  Conditional logic with the mod function is better.  Here is a simple example.

```
<cfloop query = "sheets">
<tr>
td cells and data go here:
<cfif currentrow mod 2 is 0>
</tr>
<tr>
</cfif>
```

Note that this answer is intentionally incomplete.  The part I am leaving for you is how to handle the situation where the query has an odd number of rows.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks